# How to Debug JSS Import Errors

Tags: jss, docker

I am trying to deploy a JSS app to a local containerized Sitecore Instance, but when I call `jss deploy items -c -d`, I am getting a 400 Bad Request error with no additional information.

Is there a way to get additional information about whats wrong? I don't see anything in the logs or the console output that would help me to debug what is wrong.

The app is developed by another company, so I have no idea whether something is wrong in the app itself.

Comment: Can you check your JSS compatible version with your Sitecore instance version, if it's not correct then please uninstall it through npm and then install compatible version again.

Comment: Did you try this to debug? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/debug-logging-in-jss-apps.html